# IAM Create role malformed error via boto3

Tags: boto3, amazon-iam, assume-role

Trying to set an IAM role for cross account access, wherein lambda from management account can run tasks on all other accounts by assuming cross account role. I was able to create the role n the non management account by console, but boto3 gives malformed policy document error.

LambdaCrossAccountRole is the role that has already been created in management account, and this role would need to be assumed by the role being created in non management account

The trust policy has been given as

```
trust_role="""
{
"Version":"2012-10-17",
"Statement":[{
           "Effect":"Allow",
           "Principal":{
                   "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::<management_account_id>:role/LambdaCrossAccountRole"},
    "Action":"sts.AssumeRole"}
]}"""
```

The iam role is being created by

```
iam-boto3.client("iam")
response_acct=iam.create_role(
RoleName="CrossAccountLambdaRole",
AssumeRolePolicyDocument=json.dumps(trust_role))
```

Error:

```
botocore.errorfactory.MalformedPolicyDocumentException: An error occurred(MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling CreateRole operation:This policy contains invalid Json
```

What maybe reasons for the error? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `create_role` documentation:

> AssumeRolePolicyDocument (string) [REQUIRED] -
>
> The trust relationship policy document that grants an entity permission to assume the role.
> In IAM, you must provide a JSON policy that has been converted to a string.

`AssumeRolePolicyDocument` should be a string, don't use `json.dumps()`

```
iam = boto3.client('iam')
iam.create_role(
    RoleName='TestRole',
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument=trust_role
)
```

Also update this:

```
# from this:
trust_role="""
{
...
}

# to this:
trust_role="""{
...
}
```

Otherwise it will throw an error:

```
An error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling the CreateRole operation: JSON strings must not have leading spaces
```